# AVAudioPlayer is not playing full file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

i am download a audio file from server. As it is downloading i want to start playing it so that user should not wait for long time so to handle this  i am using AVAudioPlayer.
But now as client gona release the app. we just found that AVAudioPlayer is not playing full file. It only plays that part of the file that is already downloaded at the time of initialising the AVAudioPlayer. So the remaining part that is attached to the file after the initialising the AVAudioPlayer does not get played.
Any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use AVPlayer for streaming.

```
var player:AVPlayer!
var steamingURL:NSURL = NSURL(string:playerURL)
player = AVPlayer(URL: steamingURL)
player.play()
```

Comment: no, i need to cache that content too at the same time. Client requirement :(

Comment: @Developer ok no problem. as client requirement download the file. But use avplayer for streaming.